# Smalltalk weird printing error

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

In order to "pad" a number I'm printing so that it's always a fixed number of characters, I'm making a padding string based off how many integers and in the given number:

```
pad := '    '.
(freqVal < 10) ifTrue: [ pad := '   ' ].
((freqVal < 100) & (freqVal > 9)) ifTrue: [ pad := '  ' ].
((freqVal < 1000) & (freqVal > 99)) ifTrue: [ pad := ' ' ].
stdout<<pad<<freqVal<<<<nl
```

However, the printed result always makes the variable `pad` into a letter instead of spaces like I'm assigning its value to. If I add `pad displayNl` before the last line it prints out a letter for some reason instead of just spaces.

Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Comment: When I tried this code in GNU Smalltalk, the `<<<<nl` bit gives me an error and it won't execute. If I do `pad displayNl` I don't see any extraneous character being printed. What character are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Gnu-Smalltalk in particular. Surely there are some handy String methods or formatters you could reuse for this purpose though. My advice would be to first convert the number into a String and then format it with blank-padding. That way you will avoid type conversion Problems which you've experienced

new String method (preferrably an existing one in your ST Distribution):

```
withLeading: aCharacter size: anInteger
   (anInteger < self size) ifTrue: [^self copyFrom: 1 to: anInteger].
   ^((self species new: anInteger - self size) atAllPut: aCharacter ), self
```

usage example

```
9 asString withLeading: ($ ) size: 10           "result '         9'"
10 asString withLeading: ($ ) size: 10          "result '        10'"
999 asString withLeading: ($ ) size: 10         "result '       999'"
```